# Stein's Paradox and credibility theory

Tags: steins-phenomenon

Stein's paradox says that

> The ordinary decision rule for estimating the mean of a multivariate
>   Gaussian distribution is inadmissible under mean squared error risk in
>   dimension at least 3 ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_Stein%27s_example))

I am curious if there is a relationship between this and [credibility theory](https://www.soa.org/files/pdf/c-24-05.pdf) (See also [credibility theory for dummies](http://www.casact.net/pubs/forum/03wforum/03wf621.pdf)). They seem to me to be the same thing, just stated differently.

For instance, suppose we have the batting averages of 18 baseball players for their first 45 times at bat during a season [Efron,Morris](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~ckirby/brad/other/Article1977.pdf). Both Credibility Theory and Stein's Paradox suggest that using these batting averages to project their end of season batting averages is not optimal; there is a better way to do this which uses the average of the 18 batting averages computed at the beginning of the season.

Comment: Stein's quoted paradox is a precise fact about a multivariate Gaussian distribution. I don't understand what kind of relationship with a theory do you expect ?

Comment: They seem related to me. The James-Stein estimator and credibility theory can both be seen as Empirical Bayes methods.

Comment: It might help to link to a more compact summary of credibility theory, for the uninitiated.

Comment: I added a link. Credibility theory is part of the curriculum for actuarial exams.

Comment: See [this paper](http://www.actuaries.org/EVENTS/Congresses/Cape_Town/Papers/Non-Life%20Insurance%20(ASTIN)/07_final%20paper_Kudryavtsev.pdf) claiming "The credibility estimator may be viewed as a particular case of Stein‐type and ridge regression estimators."